# Order of execution of f:event causing exception

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl, facelets

I am trying to run f:event when the page loads. `f:event` is associated with the backing bean function `init()`. The `init()` creates the session object `toIndex` which is used in the `getStatusList()` function. But the problem that I am facing is that the `getStatusList()` funciton is executed first and hence it cannot find the `toIndex` session object,and its giving me a null pointer exception. The `init()` function is never called. The `StatusBean` is session scoped.

1)xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<f:view>
    <f:event type="postAddToView" listener="#{statusBean.init}" ></f:event>
</f:view>
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <c:forEach var="p" items="#{statusBean.statusList}"
                        varStatus="loop">
     //content
    </c:forEach>

</h:body>
</html>
```

2) Backing bean

```
public class StatusBean  {

public List<Status> getStatusList() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
                .getSession(true);
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Status s WHERE s.email='"
                + user.getEmail() + "' ORDER BY s.timeMillis desc",
                Status.class);
        List<Status> results = query.getResultList();

        Collections.sort(results);
        int toIndex = (int) session.getAttribute("toIndex");
        List<Status> subList = results.subList(0, toIndex);
        return subList;

    }
public void init(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
        System.out.println("inside init");
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        int toIndex = 5;
        session.setAttribute("toIndex",toIndex);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem here is the `c:forEach`. It is executed when the view is built (probably before the event is triggered). Try to replace it with `ui:repeat`. Generally, `c:forEach` should be used with care (if at all) with JSF as it has side effects.

Comment: actually I tried using `ui:repeat` but I was having issues, even tried using `h:dataTable` same case. So I was only left with the option of `c:forEach`. Is there any alternative where I can trigger the `init` before `getStatusList`.

Comment: What's the problem with `ui:repeat`? It should normally have similiar behavior with better integration into JSF.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501700/submit-not-working-inside-uirepeat. Check out this question of mine. I posted it long time back

Comment: I added an answer to the linked question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186966/passing-parameters-using-uirepeat would you please see this question of mine, If I can solve this I can easily use ui:repeat in my application.